# 2 background image slider with image array

Tags: jquery, image

i want to use two different image sliders which use different images. The images should be shown depending on the class of the container. imgArray for the container with the class .second-row1 and imgArray2 for the container with the class .second-row2. Unfortunately it only shows the images of the imgArray for both containers. Does somebody know why?

```
     var imgArray = [
      '/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/image.jpg',
      '/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/image2.jpg',
      '/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/image3.jpg',
    ];

     var imgArray2 = [
      '/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/image4.jpg',
      '/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/image5.jpg',
      '/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/image6.jpg',
    ];

    function swapImages(index, slider, imageArray) {
      var nextBG = 'url(' + imageArray[index] + ') no-repeat bottom center';
      jQuery(slider).fadeOut('slow', function () {
      jQuery(this).css('background', nextBG).fadeIn('slow');
      });
    }

    function bgImageSlider(slider, images) {
      let index = 0;
      let interval = 4000;
  
      swapImages(index, slider, imgArray);
  
      setInterval(function () {
      index += 1;
  
      if (images.length === index) {
      index = 0;
      }
  
      swapImages(index, slider, imgArray);
      }, interval); // 3 second interval
      }

    bgImageSlider('.second-row1', imgArray);
    bgImageSlider('.second-row2', imgArray2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass the image array to the swapImages function as well

```js
    function swapImages(index, slider, imageArray) {
      var nextBG = 'url(' + imageArray[index] + ') no-repeat bottom center';
      jQuery(slider).fadeOut('slow', function () {
      jQuery(this).css('background', nextBG).fadeIn('slow');
      });
    }
```

and in bgImageSlider

```js
  swapImages(index, slider, imgArray);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... i edited my code. but i have the same issue as before. plz take a look to my code in the question

Comment: Can you provide an example or link?

Comment: https://raepitzer-aussicht.de/ the two background slider (next to violett boxes)

Comment: You pass the image array to `bgImageSlider` named `images` but then proceed to call `swapImages(index, slider, imgArray);`. Change it to `swapImages(index, slider, images);`